# How to create a matrix for specific elements in R and keep on adding to it

Tags: r, dataframe, select, dplyr, filter

I am trying to create a matrix in R.
I have two files: one correspond to brain model and whole blood file.
They look like this:

[image]

[image]

I want to create one big matrix for individual genes like this:
gene1 rs1 rs2 rs3 ...
whole
brain
gene2 rs1 rs2 rs3
whole
brain

and so on ...
So first I find the union set of rsid between these two file and then find union number of genes.

```r
sqlite <- dbDriver("SQLite")
dbname <- "en_Whole_Blood.db" 
db = dbConnect(sqlite,dbname)
wholeblood_df <- dbGetQuery(db,"SELECT * FROM weights") 
View(wholeblood_df)
dbname <- "en_Brain_Cortex.db" 
db = dbConnect(sqlite,dbname)
braincortex_df <- dbGetQuery(db,"SELECT * FROM weights") 
View(braincortex_df)
##union snp:
snp_between_whole_brain <- c(braincortex_df$rsid,wholeblood_df$rsid)
snp_union <- unique(snp_between_whole_brain)
cols_length <- length(snp_union)
x_rownames <- list.files("C:/Users/Downloads/data/models_file/test_Code")
models_df_between_whole_brain <- matrix(,nrow=length(x_rownames),ncol=cols_length)
colnames(models_df_between_whole_brain) <- snp_union
rownames(models_df_between_whole_brain) <- x_rownames
total_genes <- c(braincortex_df$gene,wholeblood_df$gene)
genes_union <- unique(total_genes)
models_df_between_whole_brain <- as.data.frame(models_df_between_whole_brain)
```

Once I have created a dataframe it look like this:

[image]

But I want to create a dataframe for each gene in one only:
like this

```
gene1 rs1 rs2 rs3
brain
blood
#gene2 rs1 rs2 rs3
brain
blood
```

#the number of rows will be same for all the gene.
#Then after creating the matrix i want to match the rsid. so if rsid1 is present in brain then its corresponding weight should be added instead of NA and if not then it gets 0 value. But I want to do this for all the genes.

I wrote this code:

```r
for(i in 1:length(genes_union)){for(j in 
    1:length(colnames(models_df_between_whole_brain))){x <- 
    (braincortex_df %>% filter(braincortex_df$gene == 
    genes_union[i], braincortex_df$rsid  
    %in% colnames(models_df_between_whole_brain)[j]) %>% 
    select(weight)) if(is.na(x)=FALSE)  
    {models_df_between_whole_brain[1, j]=weight} else 
    {models_df_between_whole_brain[1,j]=0}}}
```

the above code is giving me error

```r
Error: unexpected 'if' in "for(i in 1:length(genes_union)){for(j in 1:length(colnames(models_df_between_whole_brain))){x <- (braincortex_df %>% filter(braincortex_df$gene==genes_union[i],braincortex_df$rsid%in%colnames("
```

I am not able to understand how to create the entire matrix or dataframe for all the genes.
Can anyone give me some idea or advice on how to solve this.

I tried the above code that I mentioned. I am able to do it for 1st col 1st row but not able to fill it for all the rsid and for all the genes

> I used the comment approach and got this:  [enter image description
> here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zFbsq.png)

These are the inputs:

```
x <- str(wholeblood_df)
'data.frame':   206238 obs. of  7 variables:
 $ gene      : chr  "ENSG00000107937.18" "ENSG00000107937.18" "ENSG00000107937.18" "ENSG00000107937.18" ...
 $ rsid      : chr  "rs7475652" "rs7918643" "rs3125034" "rs3750730" ...
 $ varID     : chr  "chr10_295356_T_C_b38" "chr10_301812_C_T_b38" "chr10_302079_G_C_b38" "chr10_653149_A_G_b38" ...
 $ ref_allele: chr  "T" "C" "G" "A" ...
 $ eff_allele: chr  "C" "T" "C" "G" ...
 $ weight    : num  0.00454 -0.00735 0.00691 0.01152 0.01207 ...
 $ matrix    : chr  "wholeblood" "wholeblood" "wholeblood" "wholeblood" ...
> y <- str(braincortex_df)
'data.frame':   176364 obs. of  7 variables:
 $ gene      : chr  "ENSG00000185736.15" "ENSG00000185736.15" "ENSG00000185736.15" "ENSG00000185736.15" ...
 $ rsid      : chr  "rs2085346" "rs12765102" "rs11250286" "rs1876899" ...
 $ varID     : chr  "chr10_617697_G_A_b38" "chr10_1142141_G_T_b38" "chr10_1149946_C_T_b38" "chr10_1154505_A_C_b38" ...
 $ ref_allele: chr  "G" "G" "C" "A" ...
 $ eff_allele: chr  "A" "T" "T" "C" ...
 $ weight    : num  -0.05847 0.00128 0.00176 -0.00193 0.00182 ...
 $ matrix    : chr  "braincortex" "braincortex" "braincortex" "braincortex" ...
```

Answer (score 0):

on approach:

create example data - you forgot to provide some other than a screenshot ;-)

```
wholeblood_df <- structure(list(gene = c("ENSG0000123456", "ENSG0000123987"), 
    rsid = c("rs7470815", "rs3853288"), varID = c("foo", "baz"
    ), ref_allele = c("C", "T"), eff_allele = c("A", "G"), weight = c(0.001, 
    0.001)), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1:2)
braincortex_df <- structure(list(gene = c("ENSG0000123456", "ENSG0000123987"), 
    rsid = c("rs7470815", "rs3853288"), varID = c("ping", "pong"
    ), ref_allele = c("C", "T"), eff_allele = c("A", "G"), weight = c(NA, 
    0.009)), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1:2)
```

merging and reshaping with {tidyr} and {dplyr}:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

## add a column indicating the data provenance for later ...
wholeblood_df$matrix = 'wholeblood'
braincortex_df$matrix = 'braincortex'

bind_rows( ## rowbind the required portions (columns) of both datasets:
  braincortex_df |> select(matrix, gene, rsid, weight),
  wholeblood_df |> select(matrix, gene, rsid, weight)
) |>
pivot_wider( ## juxtapose 'weight' of blood and brain:
  names_from = matrix,
  values_from = weight
) |>
## coalesce weight values = keep first non-NA value in a row
## 'brain' comes first, so weight will be taken from this column unless NA
mutate(braincortex = coalesce(braincortex, wholeblood)) |>
## re-pivot to long format:
pivot_longer(cols = c(braincortex, wholeblood),
             names_to = 'matrix',
             values_to = 'weight'
) |>
select(matrix, gene, rsid, weight) |>
pivot_wider(names_from = rsid,
            values_from = weight
            ) |>
select(-matrix)
```

output:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 3
  gene           rs7470815 rs3853288
  <chr>              <dbl>     <dbl>
1 ENSG0000123456     0.001    NA    
2 ENSG0000123456     0.001    NA    
3 ENSG0000123987    NA         0.009
4 ENSG0000123987    NA         0.001
```

Comment: Hello, i tried to use your code. and I am getting like this: Please check the edited post

Comment: can you also please explain your answer. it will help me to understand it

Comment: I am getting it for all the genes. what I want to do is create a whole matrix for entire gene wherein rows are tissue and col are rsid.

Comment: I have also added the input values for reference

Comment: can you also tell me how to output this in a variable rather than printout in the console

Comment: see edited answer please; to save the output in a variable, prepend `bind_rows(...)` with the object name you want for it and the assignment operator, e.g. `my_result <- bind_rows(...)` - not different from the way you would treat other output in R

Comment: I tried to use the edited code but its giving me error: Error in `vec_init()`:
! `n` must be a single number, not an integer `NA`.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
Warning message:
In nrow * ncol : NAs produced by integer overflow